# UPDATE for add spaces in specific places | SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add spaces in specific places of my string if `it's < 143`(the normal length of a row Regist) , if it's less of 143 then take the difference and add that quantity of ' ' Spaces. The update doesn't work, when I execute, it appears like affect rows but when i look for the `LEN` of the row that change it doesn't do anything. I am using this:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Regist = (SUBSTRING(Regist,1,(57 - (143 - LEN(Regist)))) +
             REPLICATE(' ',(143 - LEN(Regist))) + SUBSTRING(Regist,(58 - (143 - LEN(Regist))),(LEN(Regist) - (58 - (143 - LEN(Regist))))))     
WHERE 
     (LEN(Regist) - 143) < 0 
  AND Name = 'SQL SERVER V2008'
```

**Example:**

[Name]

Excel

--This row has length 142 (including the spaces after v2008)

[Regist]

ABCDEF12345678910111213411121341SQL SERVER V2008         A1111111111111 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

So, i did that update to add a space (Just 1 in this case 143 - 142) in the place 56 (because i know that the name finish in place 57 but the row length is less 143, then 57 - (143-142 ) = 56 and that is the position of where is going to be the space.

Comment: You see message of affected that doesn't mean that the rows are updated, it could be `(0 row(s) affected)` message.

Comment: Please provide all the rules regarding where space-padding is needed, since `Regist` contains multiple data elements in a single string (never a good idea).  Is there any way to get the various data elements separately?

Comment: Yes, thats because with ssis i took a flat file and then put in data in a table. Then in diferents table takes the data that need each other tables. So with substrings i can take the info. But i think that the update is not working.

Comment: You could probably change the column definition to CHAR(143)?

Answer (score 1):

`LEN` won't be a good tell of this.  It doesn't count trailing blank space.

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing blanks.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You could do something like:

```
SELECT LEN(Regist + 'x') - 1
```

Which would then count your blanks.  (Note, you should do this for your length checks in your update too.  Otherwise you may be adding way more blank space then you intend, especially if you run multiple times.)

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
DECLARE @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(100) = 'SQL SERVER V2008'

SELECT REGIST, 
     LEFT(REGIST,CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,REGIST,1) + LEN(@SEARCHSTRING) -1) + REPLICATE(' ',143 - LEN(REGIST)) + RIGHT(REGIST,143 - LEN(LEFT(REGIST,CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,REGIST,1) + LEN(@SEARCHSTRING) -1)) - (143 - LEN(REGIST)))
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name = @SearchString
AND LEN(REGIST) < 143

--UPDATE yourTable
--SET Regist = LEFT(REGIST,CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,REGIST,1) + LEN(@SEARCHSTRING) -1) + REPLICATE(' ',143 - LEN(REGIST)) + RIGHT(REGIST,143 - LEN(LEFT(REGIST,CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,REGIST,1) + LEN(@SEARCHSTRING) -1)) - (143 - LEN(REGIST)))
--WHERE Name = @SEARCHSTRING --Or whatever conditions you want
--AND LEN(Regist) < 143
```

Here is a breakdown you can run to see what's happening:

```
DECLARE @REGIST VARCHAR(200) = 'ABCDEF12345678910111213411121341SQL SERVER V2008 A1111111111111 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
DECLARE @REGISTLENGTH INT = LEN(@REGIST)
DECLARE @NUMSPACES INT = 143 - LEN(@REGIST)
DECLARE @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(100) = 'SQL SERVER V2008'
DECLARE @LOCATION INT = CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,@REGIST,1) + LEN(@SEARCHSTRING) -1
DECLARE @LEFTPART VARCHAR(200) = LEFT(@REGIST,@LOCATION)
DECLARE @RIGHTPART VARCHAR(200) = RIGHT(@REGIST,143 - LEN(@LEFTPART) - @NUMSPACES) 
DECLARE @NEWREGIST VARCHAR(200) = @LEFTPART + REPLICATE(' ',@NUMSPACES) + @RIGHTPART 
DECLARE @NEWREGISTLENGTH INT = LEN(@NEWREGIST) 

PRINT 'Original string: ' + @REGIST
PRINT 'Original length: ' + CAST(@REGISTLENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))
PRINT 'Spaces to add: ' + CAST(@NUMSPACES AS VARCHAR(10))
PRINT 'Searchstring: ' + @SEARCHSTRING
PRINT 'Left of searchstring: ' + @LEFTPART
PRINT 'Right of searchstring: ' + @RIGHTPART
PRINT 'New string: ' + @NEWREGIST
PRINT 'New string length: ' + CAST(@NEWREGISTLENGTH AS VARCHAR(10))
```

If you take the final `@NEWREGIST` line and break it's parts back down, you'll be left with the update above.

The main goal here was is to make the select/update more scale-able.  You can change `@SEARCHSTRING` to anything you want and this will add the correct number of spaces after that string.

Comment: Yes, but i don´t want to count the trailing, justthe caracters that are in the row (including the spaces between, not in the trailing)

Comment: @Mar Add an example to your question that shows how the string currently looks and how you want it to end up looking.

Comment: @Mar Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
UPDATE yt SET 
    yt.Regist = LEFT(yt.Regist + REPLICATE(' ', 143), 143)
FROM
    dbo.YourTable yt
WHERE 
    yt.name = 'Excel'
    AND LEN(yt.Regist) < 143;
```